# Write the headers & query to the csv

Tags: python, csv, psycopg2

I am trying to save the query results from postgresql into a csv file but the csv file sometimes lacks the headers but writes all the details of the queries.

```
import psycopg2
import csv

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = '', user = '', host = '', password = '')
except:
    print ("I am unable to connect to the database")

cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """select * from"""

cursor.execute(query)

result = cursor.fetchall()

with open("kiker.csv","wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ["Builder", "Subdivision", "Spec", "Build", "Cancel", "Price", "Sq_Ft", "PPSF", "Realtor", "Project ID"], extrasaction = 'ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(result)

print "Query 1 Created"
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\connecting.py", line 45, in   <module>
    writer.writerow(result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    return [rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I tried both the methods below, but both of them fail to include the header information from postgresql.

```
c = csv.writer(open("kiker.csv","wb"))

for row in result:
    c.writerow(row)
```

and

```
fp = open("kiker.csv","wb")
myFile = csv.writer(fp)
myFile.writerows(result)
fp.close()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: the part of the code that raises an error is not posted.

Comment: Added two more lines to the error. `writer.writerow(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Pandas to get around the situation. Worked like a treat.

```
cursor.execute(query)

result = cursor.fetchall()

first = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ["Builder","Subdivision","Spec","Build","Cancel","Price","Sq_Ft","PPSF","Realtor","Project ID"])

first.to_csv("kiker.csv",index = False)
```

Comment: thanks, will this create a new csv on the fly ? how can we save file at a specified location ? is it possible to add more details to the csv to make it prettier like a report or something ?

Comment: @viki, Yes this will save the results from the **first** variable into a csv file in your working directory. And if you covet to save it some other place, you would need to jot the direct path.

Answer (score 0):

DictWriter expects dicts, not tuples: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#writer-objects